# Borromean signatures in monero commiting to an empty string？

Tags: security, ringct

In the codebase, the Borromean signatures to reduce the size of range proofs seem to sign an empty string，which is different from the paper by Maxwell et al. Is it true? Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Could you link to the spot in the code you are referencing?